# ¿ Como cambiar valores de un array dentro de un contexto de React?

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, typescript, context

Estoy realizando una tradicional app de ToDos con React y context API para compartir el estado en tre los componentes, ya logré hacerlo con un estado para cambiar el tema a oscuro/claro de la app, pero no entiendo muy bien como hacerlo con las tareas (todos)

De esta manera creo el contexto:

```
import { createContext } from "react";
import { ToDo } from "../types";

export  const TodosContext = createContext({
    todos: [
        {
            id: 1,
            text: 'Complete online JavaScript course',
            done: true
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            text: 'Jog around the park 3x',
            done: false
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            text: '10 minutes meditation',
            done: false
          },
    ],
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
    setTodos: (todos:ToDo[]) => {
        console.log(todos)
this.todos = todos
        
    },
});
```

Y este es el componente de un ToDo individual y donde quiero cambiar el estado de un ToDo en específico:

```
const Todo = ({text, done, id}:ToDo) => {

  const { todos, setTodos } = useContext(TodosContext);

  const handleDone = (e:any) => {
    const newTodos = todos.map(todo => {
      if(todo.id === id) {
        return {
          ...todo,
          done: !todo.done
        }
      }
      return todo
    })
    setTodos(newTodos)
  }

  return (
    <div className='todo-wrapper'>
        <div className="done-name">
            {/* Only show check mark when todo is done */}
            {/* {done ? <img className='check' src="/icon-check.svg" alt="" />: ''}       */}
            <input onChange={handleDone} checked={done} type="checkbox" name="done" id="done" />
            <span className={`todo-text ${done ? 'done' : ''}`}>{text}</span>
        </div>
        <img src="/icon-cross.svg" alt="" />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Todo
```

En resumen, cuando cambio el "checked" de un ToDo quiero que se actualice en el contexto global, el problema es que no lo hace y en la linea en que seteo los ToDos en el contexto me sale el error:

```
this.todos = todos; // Object is possibly undefined.
```

Como puedo cambiar los valores dentro del array y que se actualicen ?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Errores al implementar un componente que use el contexto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Intenta creando un Contexto y usa un componente funcional **"ContextProvider"** que te permitirá utilizar el contexto en conjunto con **useState([])** para poder manejar a lista de tareas a tu antojo, y eso te permitira que los elementos hijos del componente **"ContextProvider"** que utilicen los recursos del contexto vuelvan a renderizar la lista ni bien esta cambie:

*AppContext.tsx*

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

// tareas
const todosData: task[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "Complete online JavaScript course",
    done: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "Jog around the park 3x",
    done: false,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: "10 minutes meditation",
    done: false,
  },
];

interface AppContext { // definimos un tipo que que sera el tipo del contexto
  todos: task[]; // representa la lista de tareas del useState
  setTodos: Function; // representa la funcion setTodos del useState
} // si necesitaramos mas propiedades para el contexto deberiamos agregarlas aqui

const defValues: AppContext = { // definimos valores por defecto para el contexto
  todos: todosData,
  setTodos: () => {},
};

export const context = createContext<AppContext>(defValues); // declaramos el contexto con su tipo y sus valores por defecto

export function AppContextProvider({ children }: any) { // componente funcional proveedor, cuando lo renderizemos sus hijos podran acceder a los recursos

  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(todosData); // este useState reemplazara a los valores por defecto
  // por otro lado, definimos como valor por defecto del useState la lista de tareas
  
  return ( 
    <context.Provider value={{ todos, setTodos }}>{children}</context.Provider>
  );
}
```

Este componente proveedor del contexto estará renderizado en la raíz de mi proyecto y envolverá al componente `<App>` que a su vez envuelve al resto de mi aplicación, lo que permitirá que toda la aplicación acceda a los recursos del contexto, aunque esto es dependiendo de las necesidades claramente

*main.tsx*

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'
import { AppContextProvider } from './AppContext';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AppContextProvider>
      <App />
    </AppContextProvider>

    {/* otros contextos... */}

    {/* otros componentes... */}
    
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

*App.tsx* (componente que recorrerá la lista y renderizara los componentes ToDo)

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { context } from "./AppContext";
import ToDo from "./ToDo";

function App() {
  const { todos } = useContext(context);

  return (
    <>
      {todos.map((elem: task, i: number) => {
        return <ToDo id={elem.id} done={elem.done} text={elem.text} key={i}></ToDo>
      })}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

*ToDo.tsx*

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { context } from "./AppContext";
import "./styles/styles.css";

export default function ToDo({ text, done, id }: ToDo_Props) {
  const { todos, setTodos } = useContext(context);

  const handleDone = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const newTodos = todos.map((todo) => {
      if (todo.id === parseInt(e.target.id)) todo.done = !todo.done;
      return todo;
    });
    setTodos(newTodos);
  };

  return (
    <div className="todo-wrapper">
      <div className="done-name">
        <input
          onChange={handleDone}
          checked={done}
          type="checkbox"
          id={`${id}`}
        />
        <span className={`todo-text ${done ? "done" : ""}`}>{text}</span>
      </div>
      <img src="/icon-cross.svg" alt="" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

*Types.tsx* (para mas organización de las interfaces)

```
interface task {
  id: number,
  text: string,
  done: boolean
}

interface ToDo_Props {
  text: string, 
  done: boolean, 
  id: number
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Documentación util de [Context con TypeScript](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/context/).

Cualquier duda solo pregunta.

Comment: Estoy intentando implementar tu solución, pero tengo unos problemas en el componente que usa el contexto, coloco un screenshot con los errores.

Comment: @kilex poco me dice ese error, hablame por [aqui](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146217/myrooml)

Comment: Ya te escribí por allí